# How to create a new user with all privileges of the current user in Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, user-accounts

It is known that `useradd` is used to add new user accounts.

```
useradd newuser
```

The `-G` flag is used to add groups for respective privileges. Is there a simpler way to create a user will all privileges of a specific existing user?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a cleaner way to do this, but if I understand correctly, this should work:

```
useradd -G $(groups | tr ' ' ',') newuser
```

groups gives you a list of the groups the current user (or a different user if specified) belongs to, seperated by spaces. tr converts the spaces to commas, since that is what useradd expects.

Comment: Note that this doesn't necessarily place the user in the same "initial login group" as the current user.